# Password text & toggle without using Input Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, redaction

How do you accomplish displaying text in dots using HTML, like you would see in a password field such as this:

```
Password: <input type="password" name="pwd">This text looks like dots</input>
```

*Without* using an `<input>`? I would like to utilize the redaction from a password field outside of the context of an input form.

Think of it like a page displaying a salary and I don't want to display the information in a text box, i.e. you don't want to give the impression that you can edit your salary, but when the page loads I don't want it to be visible right away in case someone is looking. The text should show up in dots as such "Salary: ●●●●●●●● (check to view)" and then end up looking like "Salary: 54372.23 (check to hide)".

Comment: Can you please tell me why you are down-voting?

Comment: I wrote this question in general terms so others who view this could see how this would apply in the broader situation but I can make it much more specific, I'm sorry if this seems off-topic and unclear?

Comment: How is this not specific and about programing? I fail to see how this does not meet the outlined guide lines in the help center?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late?cb=1

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do this. Is there a reason you used input:password as a specific example? If it shouldn't look like editable elements, a simple span would suffice as well.

Comment: I tried <span type='password'> but it didn't work maybe I did something else wrong and this is why I'm asking such a stupid question? If that's the case I"m sorry.

Comment: I think you're a bit to fixated on `type:password`. This works only for input elements, which have their predefined behavior. But you could easily use other elements to simulate what you need. I'll add a jsfiddle shortly. Also don't bother with the question closed, chances are it won't be reopened.

Comment: OP is asking how to [redact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redaction) information in the document.

Comment: @Nimjox Create a working fiddle with your attempts there are alot of possiblities to do this.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dittodhole/hgrv9/1/

Comment: @Nimjox Edit that into your question.

Comment: A basic example could be: http://jsfiddle.net/MH2h6/

Comment: So with the above fiddle you can see the salary when the page loads. I want it to be hidden by dot's until you click the box at which point you see the numbers in plain text (which is how it shows up now). The part I don't understand is how to get them to show up as dots first but not in a value box

Comment: @2rs2ts Thanks for the edit about the redaction. I didn't know how to say it in proper terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic example could be:

```
$('[data-hidden-value] > .toggle').on('click', function () {
  var
    $wrapper = $(this).parent(),
    $display = $wrapper.find('.display'),
    revealed = $wrapper.data('revealed'),
    hiddenValue = String($wrapper.data('hidden-value'))
  ;

  $display.html(revealed ? hiddenValue.replace(/./g, '*') : hiddenValue);
  $wrapper.data('revealed', !revealed);
});
```

with the following html:

```
Salary:

<span data-hidden-value="54372.23">
  <span class="display">********</span>
  <a class="toggle">(click to toggle)</a>
</span>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MH2h6/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for thank you so much for helping me. The "data-hidden-value" is the key concept I didn't understand and couldn't find.

Comment: You're welcome. But mind that *data-hidden-value* is arbitrary, it's just a name I choose, and you could very well use another one.

Comment: Cool I didn't know I could do that.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your fiddle, it's pretty simple to get the toggling behavior by adding a quick check to see if you're displaying the hidden data or the redacted string:

```
var $magics = $('.magic');
$magics.click( function () {
    var $magic = $(this);
    var password = $magic.data('password');
    $magic.text(($magic.text() == password) ? '****' : password);
});
```

See a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dittodhole/hgrv9/1/).

But this is fruitless, because you have embedded the sensitive information into your HTML. If you want to do this *right* you're going to need to issue an AJAX request to your server to get the data you want.

Comment: I'm okay with it being there. I just don't want the info to be viewable right when the page loads. Just in case someone else is looking at the screen.